# NuxtJS Intellisense

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, nuxt.js, intellisense

I've recently started a web project using NuxtJS with Tailwind CSS as it's apparently auto-including, fast, efficient and would let me create and learn easily.

As I'm not very experimented in web and direclty learning from Tailwind and not "regular" CSS I don't know all of the style tags (`margin-left: 0` would be `mx-0` for example) and I started looking for Intellisense but none of them seems to be working.

I tried installing for NuxtJS, Tailwind, Vue, but nothing appears and when pressing `CTRL + Space` I just got a "No suggestions." (in .vue files).

Has anyone been working with NuxtJS and is using an intellisense for VSCode ?

Answer (score 0):

To get Tailwind IntelliSense, you'll have to install [Tailwind CSS IntelliSense by Tailwind](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss) to your VSCode

Comment: Well this is actually an extension I already have ( see https://i.imgur.com/2lEWIIU.png ). Not sure why nothing is suggested though.

Comment: @pironc using Vetur/Volar? What are your VScode settings?

Answer (score 0):

[WindiCSS](https://windicss.org/editors/vscode.html) is also quite popular in the Vue ecosystem, their VScode extension is more powerful and deserves a try (it's made by antfu too!).

Otherwise, if you're new to the Web I highly recommend starting by the basics (HTML, then CSS, then JS, then Vue) before reaching upon Nuxt. You will have a bad time trying to understand what is happening because of the super high abstraction.

Even if a meta-framework (like Nuxt) is quite useful, it brings a lot and you probably need to understand what you get rather than thinking that it's the default, otherwise it will have too "much magic" for your learning process.

Comment: Well I already used HTML / CSS with JS before, even though I'm obviously not the best at it, is it still possible to "switch" from my basic TailwindCSS to regular CSS in my current Vue project? i've already been doing so API calls and learning the ```if``` / ```elseif``` statements in the HTML, auto includes and such things makes it easier for me. I'm not sure if it's a good practice though. And the extension isn't working etiher (:

Comment: @pironc your first question is pretty much why I recommend learning basics at first. Of course you can use regular CSS without Tailwind. Learning HTML **then** CSS **then** JS is important. Even if it's easier at first, when you'll need to debug it you'll have a harder time. The extension is for WindiCSS yeah and apparently you're missing more basic Vue configuration beyond the Tailwind one.